# how to convert data type of images(numpy arrays) stored in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i have a column in pandas dataframe that contains multi-dimensional numpy arrays representing images and i would like to change the data type of this column elements from float to int.

```
>ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5be479c0abf4> in <module>()
----> 1 train_df['images']=np.uint8(train_df['images'])

>ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I do it?

Comment: please include sample data to make it easier for us to help you

Comment: I think you can do `df["imaged"] = df["images"].apply(int)`

Comment: train_df['images']=train_df['images'].apply(int)                                   TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
@YilunZhang

Comment: Ah, I think I understood how you are storing your data.. In that case, try something like this `df["images"].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int))`